# How to get the IP and host in Web Methods Designer?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, webmethods

I have to create a plugin which creates a template as seen below in Context Menu-

[image]

I need to get the **IP** and **Host** on which this context menu appeared. In the below case, the right click happened for Default which is localhost:5555

Any suggestions on how to get the same from within the plugin for this designer?

Comment: you can create a java service(InetAddress.getHostName) on the IntegrationServer which will fetch the details for you and use that in the template. I am not sure how exactly you are creating the plugin or how u will invoke a service on IS from your template.

Comment: The Webmethods API for Eclipse reveal all the servers currently setup in Eclipse. I am able to get all the servers through ServerConnectionManager mgr = ServerConnectionManager.getInstance(); The requirement is to get the Server IP and port related to the node in which I am operating in Package Navigator. IServerConnection API  does the job of getting the IP and port but I am unable to find on how to get the object of IServerConnection